# DBA administration anonymous block with the errors PLS-00103 , ORA-06550

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

what i do to run this script ?

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
  DBlink varchar2(20);
   type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(20);
   array array_t := array_t('A,'C','Ci') ;
BEGIN
 FOR i in 1..array.count 
   LOOP
      DBlink := array(i) 


     l_sql_stmt := 'SELECT (a.data_size + b.temp_size + c.redo_size + d.controlfile_size) as DBsize FROM (SELECT SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024/1024 data_size FROM dba_data_files'||DBlink||') a,(SELECT NVL (SUM (bytes), 0) / 1024 / 1024/1024 temp_size FROM dba_temp_files'||DBlink||') b,(SELECT SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024/1024 redo_size FROM sys.v_log'||DBlink||') c,(SELECT SUM (BLOCK_SIZE * FILE_SIZE_BLKS) / 1024 / 1024/1024 controlfile_size FROM vcontrolfile'||DBlink||') d )) ;' 
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt
       END LOOP ;
    END;
```

ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "L_SQL_STMT" when expecting one of the
following

Comment: I recommend taking this over to the [Database Administrator](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) section of stack exchange, I think you'd have better luck getting help over there.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a list of syntactical issues:

1. Your `array_t` assignment statement ommitted a single end quote after A.

   `array array_t := array_t('A','C','Ci');`
2. You need a semicolon on the `DBlink` assignment statement:

   `DBlink := array(i);`
3. With your assignment statement for `l_sql_stmt`,Your database links need the '@' symbol. Also, your semicolon should not be in quoted string.
4. The objects for which the alias, c and d, represent did not exists in my database so I removed them from my test query.
5. I assumed you wanted the output, thus I invoked `dbms_output`.

**Test script (removed database links which I do not have):**

```
    SYS@tst> DECLARE
  2    l_sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(1000);
  3    dblink        VARCHAR2(20);
  4    l_size        NUMBER;
  5  TYPE array_t IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20);
  6  ARRAY array_t := array_t('A','C','Ci');
  7  BEGIN
  8    FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.count
  9    loop
 10      dblink     := ARRAY(i);
 11      l_sql_stmt :='SELECT (a.data_size + b.temp_size) as DBsize FROM (SELECT SUM (bytes)/1024/1024/1024 data_size FROM dba_data_files) a,(SELECT NVL (SUM (bytes), 0)/1024/1024/1024 temp_size FROM dba_temp_files) b';
 12      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt INTO l_size;
 13      dbms_output.put_line('database size: '|| to_char(l_size));
 14    END loop;
 15  END;
 16  /
database size: 1013.204803466796875
database size: 1013.204803466796875
database size: 1013.204803466796875

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Here is the corrected anonymous block:**

```
    DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(1000);
  dblink        VARCHAR2(20);
  l_size        NUMBER;
TYPE array_t IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20);
ARRAY array_t := array_t('A','C','Ci');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.count
  loop
    dblink     := ARRAY(i);
    l_sql_stmt :='SELECT (a.data_size + b.temp_size + c.redo_size + d.controlfile_size) as DBsize FROM (SELECT SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024/1024 data_size FROM dba_data_files@'||dblink||') a,(SELECT NVL (SUM (bytes), 0) / 1024 / 1024/1024 temp_size FROM dba_temp_files@'||dblink||') b,(SELECT SUM (bytes) / 1024 / 1024/1024 redo_size FROM sys.v_log@'||dblink||') c,(SELECT SUM (BLOCK_SIZE * FILE_SIZE_BLKS) / 1024 / 1024/1024 controlfile_size FROM vcontrolfile@'||dblink||') d ))';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt into l_size;
    dbms_output.put_line('database '|| dblink || ' size: '|| to_char(l_size));
  END loop;
END;
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 12

Comment: @ALwaleedALdajani in my test script, I utilized `into l_size` as part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, but I did not have this in the corrected anonymous block.  Next, I ran the block with a trivial `l_sql_stmt` and the errors you cite do not occur. I was able to duplicate your error prior to that.